# WHERE clause only if variable is set

Tags: mysql, where-clause, isset

An input and script in **index.php**

```
<input type="text" class="filter" id="frClientName" name="cl_name">

<script>
    $(".filter").on('change keydown keyup', function(){
        var clname;
        clname = document.getElementById("frClientName").value;
        $("#spravaContent").load("php/search_results/sprava.php?cl_name=" + clname;
    });
</script>
```

**php/search_results/sprava.php**

```
$clname = '';
if ( isset ( $_GET['cl_name'] ) ) {
    $clname = $_GET['cl_name'];
}

$sql = ("
    SELECT * FROM `db`.`table`
    WHERE cl_full_name LIKE  '%".$_GET['cl_name']."%'
");
```

How can I use WHERE clause right and only if variable isn't empty?
Thank you for some direction.

**EDIT:**

```
$sql = ("
    SELECT * FROM `db`.`table`
    ORDER BY {$oby} {$ohow}
    WHERE cl_full_name LIKE '%".$_GET['cl_name']."%'
    OR '' = '".$_GET['cl_name']."'
    LIMIT $start_sprava,$per_page_sprava
");
```

Comment: @hjpotter92 The user inserts some client name into `input#frClientName`, then starts script, which takes value of input, saves it as `clname` var and to `div#spravaContent` prints results using `.load` from `php/search_results/sprava.php` which agrees with filters. I don't know how what you mean exactly with more elaborate. Thanks

Comment: I will appreciate, if you can tell me, if the WHERE clause is written right and how can I preclude the error of empty variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit hacky, but I've handled situations like this with a `CASE` statement. You evaluate your argument and if it doesn't meet the condition you require, you use an obviously true statement like `1=1` which has the net effect of keeping that part of the `WHERE` clause from participating in filtering the result set.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `db`.`table`
 WHERE CASE WHEN TRIM('".$_GET['cl_name']."') IS NOT NULL THEN cl_full_name LIKE  '%".$_GET['cl_name']."%'
            ELSE 1=1
       END
 ORDER BY {$oby} {$ohow}
 LIMIT {$start_sprava}, {$per_page_sprava}
;
```

Don't forget to police your inputs so you don't wind up with a [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) problem. Also, the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clauses generally come after the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Tommorow (today) I will check it, but it seems very good, thank you. Please just tell me yet. If the app is only for non-public use, is it rellevant (SQL Injection protection)?

Comment: Anyway, you helped me a lot. Thank you!

Comment: You are most welcome.

As for protecting against SQL Injection, I would say yes, even a non-public-facing, internal application behind a firewall should guard against it. It's the work of a few minutes to protect yourself and your users, but if somebody takes advantage it will take many hours of work to restore lost data.

Comment: I'm not sure that I'm able to do it well without help. I think if I can't attack, I can't resist good. But I have scheduled since I finish the app, I'll take few days to learn it and implement SQL injection protection. To the clause: I tried your version. The trim function how I found out, removes the spaces from a string. But what If i need to check if the name of client is two-word? The clause is working well, but only for one word and I'm afraid it does not help me like I need.

Comment: And I've just tried remove trim function and it still doesn't respond to second word in a string... Damn! I think for somebody I'm looking like an idiot. But I'm trying hard :)

Comment: If you `TRIM` an _empty_ string literal it will return `NULL` which is what we're after here. Notice that the second time we reference `$_GET['cl_name']` it is not trimmed. That's because if the user enters _anything_, we want to to try and match that against the rows in the database.

Comment: [According to the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim), `TRIM` only removes spaces at the beginning and end of a string. A space in the middle of a `LIKE` comparison shouldn't affect the results as long as the column you're matching against also has the space. If your users are entering more than one keyword that you want to match separately, that's an entirely different problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make the where clause work whether set or not.

Assuming your app language returns the text "null" if variable is not set:

```
"SELECT * FROM `db`.`table`
WHERE cl_full_name LIKE '%".$_GET['cl_name']."%'
OR 'null' = '".$_GET['cl_name']."'"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but it does not resolve the problem. `mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource`. I'm quite sure that variable can be sent to `php/search_results/sprava.php`, because I can print her directly...

Comment: I edited my original question, can you please look at the whole query?

Comment: The following is functional, thank you very much for your help!
` SELECT * FROM `db`.`table`
 WHERE cl_full_name LIKE '%".$_GET['cl_name']."%'
 OR '' = '".$_GET['cl_name']."'
 ORDER BY {$oby} {$ohow}
 LIMIT $start_sprava,$per_page_sprava`